# self.driver.set_script_timeout(30) is being ignored in chromedriver

Tags: python, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is being skipped in my python script it does not wait just ignores the command

```
    article1 = xpath ('//*[@id="views-bootstrap-grid-1"]/div/div/a/img')

    article1href = xpath ('//*[@id="views-bootstrap-grid-1"]/div/div/a/img').get_attribute('src')
    article1.click()
    self.driver.set_script_timeout(30)


    article1URL = currenturl
    print article1href


    print currenturl
```

Comment: You don't do anything after setting the script timeout...

Comment: Is that because of the spaces I have tried that